# WebGL: Force canvas to lose context

Tags: webgl

I'm working on a scene that will lose context once in a blue moon. I've set up event handlers to respond to these circumstances, and now need to test them.

I have tried `gl.getExtension('WEBGL_lose_context').loseContext();`, but the following event does not trigger:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#canvas');
elem.addEventListener('webglcontextlost', function(e) {
  console.log('context lost')
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Is there a way to manually lose the WebGL context? khronos.org gives a link to some JS utils that can force one to lose context, but the link is dead. Any thoughts others can offer on this question would be very welcome!

Comment: My personal conclusion is if you lose the context you should just reload the page (or offer a button to reload the page). Design your page so it doesn't lose state on reload. Good examples are probably gmail and google maps. Both keep the state either in the URL or somewhere so that reloadng brings you exactly where you left off (or close to it)

Comment: @gman thanks for your note -- this is exactly what I ended up doing, because recovery was taking me deeper into a rabbit hole. I felt like reload was a hack, but I'm glad to hear you think it's a good idea as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, my scene is in Three.js, so I needed to call the `loseContext()` method on the renderer's context:

```
renderer.context.getExtension('WEBGL_lose_context').loseContext();
```

Answer (score -1):

or simply

```
renderer.forceContextLoss();
```

[[docs](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L325)]

Comment: Can you explain that further? Where does `renderer` come from, and what does this function call do?

Comment: `renderer` is the name often used for the object returned by one of the renderer constructors in there.js (e.g. the `THREE.WebGLRenderer` constructor). This function is detailed here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L325

Answer (score -1):

You can do this like this for any type of canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
// OR if no Id
// var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

canvas.addEventListener('webglcontextlost', function(e) {
  console.log(`Lost WebGL context \n${e}`);
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);

// Bye bye canvas :)
gl.getExtension('WEBGL_lose_context').loseContext();
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_lose_context/loseContext